# Rank Two Tensor and Rank One Tensor Identities

Tags: tensors

So I am attempting to show that  $$- \nabla \cdot (T \times x) = x \times (\nabla \cdot T) + \epsilon : T$$ where $T$ is a rank two tensor, $x$ is a rank one tensor, and $\epsilon$ is the permutation symbol.

Using Einstein notation I have been able to arrive at the following:

$$
(- \nabla \cdot (T \times x))_i = (-\nabla \cdot (\epsilon_{jkm}T_{ij}x_k))_i = - \partial_m \epsilon_{jkm} T_{ij} x_k = \epsilon_{jmk} x_k \partial_m T_{ij}
$$

and

$$
(x \times (\nabla \cdot T) + \epsilon : T)_i = \epsilon_{ijk}x_j \partial_m T_{mk} + \epsilon_{ijk} T_{jk}.
$$

I am not really sure where to go from here however or if what I have above is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget the Leibniz rule (or product rule). $\partial_m(\varepsilon_{jkm}T_{ij}x_k)=\varepsilon_{jkm}\frac{\partial T_{ij}}{\partial x_m}x_k+\varepsilon_{jkm} T_{ij}\frac{\partial x_k}{x_m}$, where $\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_m}=\delta_{km}$

Comment: Also,there is something strange going on with your definition of the divergence, I would expect $\nabla\cdot T=\frac{\partial T_{rj}}{\partial x_r}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T\times x\to\varepsilon_{ijk}T_{rj}x_k$$
$$\nabla\cdot(T\times x)\to \partial_r(\varepsilon_{ijk}T_{rj}x_k)=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_rT_{rj}x_k+\varepsilon_{ijk}T_{rj}\partial_rx_k$$

using $\partial_rx_k=\delta_{rk}$

$$=-\varepsilon_{ikj}x_k\partial_rT_{rj}-\varepsilon_{ikj}T_{kj}$$

Hence $-\nabla \cdot (T\times x)=x\times(\nabla\cdot T)+\varepsilon:T$

Comment: Ahhh I see I see this is really helpful! Thank you so much!